# Mostrar todas las columnas de un dataframe

Tags: pandas, jupyter

¿Cómo se pueden mostar en pantalla todas las columnas de un DataFrame?.
En mi caso, la ejecución me indica con puntos suspensivos, las columnas no mostradas.

> ```
>                    EPSV  Acatis  Avantage   ...      Nasdaq  Nikkei_225  \
> ```
>
> Date                                            ...
>   2019-01-30 00:00:00  11.914  249.57    13.258   ...     7183.08   20556.539
>   2019-01-31 00:00:00  11.951  250.05    13.236   ...     7281.74   20773.490
>   2019-02-01 00:00:00  11.954  250.90    13.272   ...     7263.87   20788.391
>   Agradeceré vuestra ayuda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El número de columnas/filas que se muestran cuando se imprime el DataFrame está acotado por defecto en el caso de Júpiter Notebook. Ésta y otras características relevantes al mostrar datos se pueden definir mediante `pandas.options.display`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.options.display.max_rows
60

>>> pd.options.display.max_columns
20
```

Si quieres que se muestren todas (número ilimitado) solo debes asignar `None` a dichas variables.

```
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
```

`max_rows` y `max_columns` son usados por los métodos `__repr__()` de los objetos pandas como `DataFrame` para decidir si `to_string()` o `info()` se usan para representar el objeto en una cadena. Cuando la ejecución se realiza en una  terminal, el valor es 0 de manera predeterminada, permitiendo a Pandas detectar automáticamente el ancho de la terminal y ajustarse en base a ello. Cuando la ejecución no se realiza en la terminal (qtconsole, IDLE, Notebook, etc) no es posible realizar la detección automática del tamaño del área disponible, en cuyo caso el valor predeterminado se establece en 20.

Si se supera el valor se usa  `...` como marcador de posición y se muestran las dimensiones reales del mismo debajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay múltiples opciones de configuración, la lista completa y una explicación de lo que hace cada uno la [podemos ver en la documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options).

Comment: Grcias Sevilla. Me he hartado de buscar en tutoriales de jupyter, erróneamente, lo que ahora veo eran sentencias de pandas. El enlace me remite a una amplia documentación en la que merce la pena sumergirse.

Answer (score 1):

Copiado de un notebook en internet, habia colocado, a continuación de las sentencias de importación de módulos, otras que limitaban la visualización.
Silenciando las mismas, ya se muestran todas las columnas.

```
#pd.set_option('display.notebook_repr_html', False)
#pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 6)
#pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 10) 
#pd.set_option('display.width', 78) 
#pd.set_option('precision', 3)
```

Lo que no he sido capaz es de encontrar alguna Web o tutorial en el que se expliquen éstas y otras similares.

Comment: La aplicación denominada "Zeal", permite descargar y consultar la documentación de referencia de muchos lenguajes y librerias, entre ellas "jupyter notebook".

Answer (score 0):

paso uno se muestra el nombre del data frame
`dfListing.shape`

guardó los valores en una variable
`valores_columnas = dfListing.columns.values`

los convierto en lista
`valores_lista_columnas = list(valores_columnas)`

imprimis todos los valores de la variable
`print(valores_lista_columnas)`